# How to deal with a space in a c# class name?

Tags: c#, ssis

So I am pulling data from an API and using c# in a SSIS script task to parse and insert the data in SQL. Here is my troublesome class:

```
   public class Fields
  {
      public string kCode { get; set; }
      public string kCompany { get; set; }
      public string Vendor # { get; set; }
      public string kStatus { get; set; }
      public string kActive { get; set; }
      public string kExpiration { get; set; }
      public string kCombinedAPI { get; set; }
  }
```

notice where it says "Vendor #"...  I'm not sure how to treat this as a single string, or how to work around it.  Is this something where I would need to contact whoever built the API and have them remove the space or is there a work around?

Comment: you can't have a space in a C# class name (full stop)...or a hash

Comment: how are you deserializing the values returned from the API into this class?

Comment: I don't know anything about SSIS script tasks but does it expose any kind of "Preprocessor" and "Postprocessor" where you could modify this class name to be something acceptable in C#.  The Postprocessor functionality would be needed if you needed to go the other direction with your data.  Basically just a translation wrapper around this.

Comment: Ok Liam, that is what I was thinking too, but wanted to confirm before I email this dev and ask him to fix this.  The API was developed just for my needs so it's no big deal to have them fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have space in C# class name.

Most serialization libraries provide way to map persistent name to C# name, usually using attributes on properties - check serialization library you are using if it supports such mapping.